# Define a 2d list and append lists to it in a for loop, scala

Tags: scala, list, append, 2d

I want to define a 2d list before a for loop and afterwards I want to append to it 1d lists in a for loop, like so:

```
var 2dEmptyList: listOf<List<String>> 
for (element<-elements){
    ///do some stuff
    2dEmptyList.plusAssign(1dlist) 
}
```

The code above does not work. But I can't seem to find a solution for this and it is so simple!

Comment: You want to define a `List[List[String]]` and append new `List[String]`s to it from within a for loop on a `List[String]`?

Comment: yes, exactly. you described it better than I did.

Comment: Are you sure this is Scala? Looks like kotlin (`listOf`, `<` not `[`).

Comment: It surely is Scala :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
scala> val elements = List("a", "b", "c")
elements: List[String] = List(a, b, c)

scala> val twoDimenstionalList: List[List[String]] = List.empty[List[String]]
twoDimenstionalList: List[List[String]] = List()

scala> val res = for(element <- elements) yield twoDimenstionalList ::: List(element)
res: List[List[java.io.Serializable]] = List(List(a), List(b), List(c))
```

Better still:

```
scala> twoDimenstionalList ::: elements.map(List(_))
res8: List[List[String]] = List(List(a), List(b), List(c))
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want `2dEmptyList` be mutable, please consider using `scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer`:

```
scala> val ll = scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer.empty[List[String]]
ll: scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer[List[String]] = ListBuffer()

scala> ll += List("Hello")
res7: ll.type = ListBuffer(List(Hello))

scala> ll += List("How", "are", "you?")
res8: ll.type = ListBuffer(List(Hello), List(How, are, you?))
```